# What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses in regard to lists?

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, pattern-matching, type-mismatch

As the title implies, I am unsure about the difference between square brackets and parentheses in regard to lists.

Two versions of Haskell's `insert` defined, one using square brackets, the other using parentheses:

```
insert' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert' y [] = [y]
insert' y (x:xs) | y <= x = y:x:xs | otherwise = x : insert' y xs
----
insert' y [x:xs] | y <= x = y:x:xs | otherwise = x : insert' y xs
```

What is the reason the second definition of `insert'` doesn't work?

The error message it gives, for anyone wondering:

```
test.hs:3:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int]’
    • In the pattern: x : xs
      In the pattern: [x : xs]
      In an equation for ‘insert'’:
          insert' y [x : xs]
            | y <= x = y : x : xs
            | otherwise = x : insert' y xs
  |
3 | insert' y [x:xs] | y <= x = y:x:xs | otherwise = x : insert' y xs
  |
```

Comment: FWIW, this question comes up really often. I always find it fascinating that this trips people up for lists specifically, and no other data type. For example, with `data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)`, no one asks why `Tree Branch l r` isn't the right pattern to match a branch. It's not just prefix-vs-infix or a namespace collision, either; similarly nobody ever asks why `Complex a :+ b` isn't the right pattern to match a complex number. But when it's lists all of a sudden some remnant of the type should/could appear in the patterns? Human brains are so complicated!

Comment: it's really very simple. `[x]` as a type matches a list of any length. `[x]` as a pattern looks exactly the same.

Comment: IIRC someone asked about using `Branch (Tree l) (Tree r)` as a pattern, though.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I believe it’s a misdirection caused by the fact that the type `[x]` means “list of any number of values of type `x`”, sugar for `[] x`, while the pattern `[x]` means “singleton list of value `x`”, sugar for something quite different, `x : []` = `(:) x []`. Using `[]` as a “sigil” in one context makes it plausible to try using that way in a similar-looking context. If we had such sugar for other types, like if `Maybe` were spelled `data a? = () | a?`, I bet we’d see similar confusion about what `f (x?)` should match.

Comment: @JonPurdy I believe this misdirection -- `[]` meaning different things at type and computation level -- is what I'm calling "namespace collision" in my comment. How do you explain that nobody then confuses type-level `Complex` with computation-level `Complex`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I *do* see that type of confusion often, both here and on Reddit in /r/haskell & /r/haskellquestions. It produces many different scope/type errors, and manifests in many ways—e.g., `Maybe x` instead of `Just x`; `Branch a (Tree l) (Tree r)`, `Tree x l r`, `Tree (Branch x l r)`, or `Branch b` + `left b`/`value b` instead of `Branch x l r`; or given `data Tree = Leaf a | Node [Tree a]`, using `Node [Tree a]` instead of `Node ts`. It’s compounded by the pedagogical difficulties with H98 `data` definitions (vs. `GADTSyntax`) that lead to interpreting `Foo f` as `f :: Foo`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm similarly surprised but just how much people trip up on this specifically. I think ultimately it's just that it is so obvious when you know the (actually quite simple) rules about types vs expressions vs patterns, but you have to know them before it's obvious. **I** prefer to learn new syntax by being told (or figuring out) the underlying rules and memorising them, so this particular confusion seems alien to me; one of the *first* things I'd get down about Haskell is that stuff inside square brackets are elements of the list, but using `:` describes the list itself. (1/2)

Comment: @DanielWagner But I think many (even most?) people don't actually focus on the formal rules when they're learning a new language's syntax, rather they copy and adapt and experiment until gradually their intuitive understanding is moulded into a shape that matches the formal rules. I think these sorts of questions are much more likely to occur on that sort of path to understanding a new language than the one I would normally try to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(x:xs)` as a pattern will match any non-empty list with `x` its head and `xs` its tail.

`[x:xs]` as a pattern will match a singleton list -- a list containing exactly one item -- which is a non-empty list, matching the pattern `(x:xs)`. The pattern `[x:xs]` is in fact equivalent to the pattern `[(x:xs)]`. It is a *nested* pattern, and Haskell allows that. The outer pattern matches a singleton list, and the inner pattern matches a non-empty list. The parentheses in this position are optional.

That's why your second definition implies the type of the second argument is `[[a]]`, but you've declared it to be `[Int]`. And `Int` can't match `[a]`. (That `a` is also determined to be an `Int`, since you compare `x` and `y`, and `y` the first argument is declared to be an `Int`, but that doesn't change anything).

```
     [ [a] ]
     [ Int ]
 ----------------
  ***mismatch***
```

Comment: It might be worth explicitly pointing out that there's no syntactic "magic" behind the parentheses in `(x:xs)`, and that they're only used because of precedence (`insert y x:xs` would be parsed as `(insert y x) : xs`)

Comment: It might be useful to show that in other positions, besides formal arguments, it doesn't require parenthesis, like in `\(xs::[Int]) -> case xs of { hd:tl -> 0; _ -> 1 }`, for a one liner.

Comment: @pedrofurla one specific question, one specific answer. :) besides, it's complicated, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't, so why complicate the answer needlessly.

Comment: Well, it shows that the () are not same as [].

Comment: @pedrofurla  your example is invalid without an extension. and of course () is not [], the question doesn't ask whether they are the same, it asks what is that difference and why it causes that error they are observing.

Comment: Which extension?

Comment: ScopedTypeVariables. "in other positions, besides formal arguments, it doesn't require parenthesis" no, e.g. using @-patterns also requires the use of parentheses (e.g. `case [1,2] of { g@(x:_) -> (x,g) }`). I'm sure there are more corner cases for that. as I said, it is complicated, non-uniform, and would needlessly complicate the answer.

Answer (score 9):

As in almost all other languages, parentheses in Haskell don't really *do* anything. They help the parser know which things you intended to group together, and that's it; they don't change the meaning of the thing that's inside them, and if the parser could magically guess which way you intended to group things at every choice point we wouldn't need them at all. So all of these patterns behave *exactly* the same:

```
x
(x)
((x))
(((((((((x)))))))))
```

All of these patterns are also exactly the same:

```
x:xs
(x:xs)
((x:xs))
(((((((((x:xs)))))))))
```

Sometimes we must use one of the later ones -- like `(x:xs)` -- instead of the first one -- `x:xs` -- to inform the parser that we intended these things to be grouped together. But the parentheses don't otherwise change anything about what the pattern means.

Square brackets, on the other hand, are used for constructing lists. They have an actual run-time meaning: they allocate a new data structure in memory and initialize it. For example, `3` is a number, but `[3]` is a list with a single element, `[3,4]` is a list with two elements, `[[3]]` is a list of lists, and so on. The same behavior applies to patterns:

```
x -- match anything (even a list!) and bind x to its value
[x] -- match a list with a single element, and bind x to that element's value
[x,y] -- match a list with two elements, and bind x and y to those elements' values
[[x]] -- match a nested list; the outer and inner lists both have one element; bind x to the first element's first element
```

Now we can address your specific example. The pattern `x:xs` is a pattern that matches any list with at least one element, binding `x` to that first element and `xs` to the rest of the list. The pattern `(x:xs)` does exactly the same thing. The pattern `[x:xs]`, on the other hand, matches a list with exactly one element, because there are square brackets; the only element of that list is then matched against the pattern `x:xs`, with the behavior described above.

One consequence of this is that `x:xs` can match lists with any type of element -- say, `Int` -- but `[x:xs]` can only match lists whose elements are lists.